# How make the result of floating an element just affect its following siblings not other following elements?

Tags: css, css-float

How make the result of floating an element just affect its following siblings not other following elements?

I mean other (not sibling) following block-level elements rendered normally under those columns created by floating siblings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to tell the siblings of the parent of the floats to clear. You can do this either with a clearfix on the parent or by applying clear directly to the parent's immediate sibling.

For example, if you have a structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>Float</div>
    <div>Float, following sibling</div>
    <div>Float, following sibling</div>
</div>
<div>Outside of .parent</div>
<div>Outside of .parent</div>
```

With this CSS:

```css
.parent div {
    float: left;
}
```

You can prevent the floats from affecting the outside elements by telling the first one of them to clear:

```css
.parent + div {
    clear: both;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/uNeGb)

You don't have to tell descendants of those floats to clear because descendants of floats should *never* interfere with floating. The only concern here are following elements that aren't siblings to the floats.